# Parent process doesn't read form pipe

Tags: c++, linux, fork, pipe

I have something like this:

```
pipe
close(pipe[0]);
parent writes something to pipe
close(pipe[1]);
fork();
if(child)
{
  close(pipe[1]);
  child reads from pipe
  close(pipe[0]);
  child does some operations
  child writes to pipe
  close(pipe[1]);
}
else
{
  back to parent
  close(pipe[0]);
  wait(&code);
  parent tries to read what the terminated child just wrote but fails to do so
}
```

I'm not really sure what can i do to make the parent read from the terminated child. Do i need to make use of `dup`? I'm not so very sure in what situations `dup` or `dup2` is useful.

writing and reading is done using the `write()` and `read()` functions.

I have to use pipes and not fifo's or other means to communicate between processes.

Comment: You might find this article useful: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html

Comment: @thirtythreeforty I won't post my code because it's a ton of it and i see no point in doing this, if i explained my issue clearly. I have a child process that ends, and the parent cannot read from the pipe afterwards. I am aware of dup and dup2 but i don't know how and when to use those and if using them can help me.

Comment: Well, at least post a compilable example.  There are many, many potential things that could be wrong, from typos to an angry compiler ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample from [this article](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html) says:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>

    main()
    {
            int     fd[2];
            pid_t   childpid;

            pipe(fd);

            if((childpid = fork()) == -1)
            {
                    perror("fork");
                    exit(1);
            }

            if(childpid == 0)
            {
                    /* Child process closes up input side of pipe */
                    close(fd[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                    /* Parent process closes up output side of pipe */
                    close(fd[1]);
            }
            .
            .
    }
```

IIRC that's the way doing it. The crucial thing is to close the unused fd's in parent and child process.

Comment: Indeed the problem was the closing of the pipes before doing the opposite action(read/write) thank you !

Comment: Actually there is a issue, it doesn't fix anything for me. I updated my question with further details.

Comment: Yet again, i missed one small detail that ruined the entire program. It was just a tiny trivial error.

Comment: @Edeph You need to do the close only once in each of the branches parent/child as shown in the example. Then write/read your data from the unclosed handle, and close in each path when you're completely finished.

Comment: Indeed after some testing i noticed that, though the main error was because i was writing in the wrong way before the child process ended. And there was actually no value to be read in the pipe. It was such a tiny error.

Comment: @Edeph Glad you could solve it! That's the reason why the people here ask for real code. Usually you should try boiling down your code sample to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces the erroneous behavior.

Comment: I actually went through the problem several times and debugged it and stuff but this just went by without me noticing it.

Answer (score 1):

I think `fifo` suites your need and I don't think you need to use a `dup` either. Here is a working code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
int main()
{
int e=open("fif",O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK);
if(fork()==0)
{
    int d=open("fif",O_WRONLY);
    write(d,"hi there\n",9);
    close(d);
    //sleep(5);
    exit(0);
}
wait();
char buf[15];
int n=read(e,buf,15);
buf[n]=0;
printf("%s", buf);
//wait();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I need to use pipes for this one. It's a requirement, i'm sorry.

Comment: @Edeph It's the same principle. If you would have read the article link I've given you, you would see ...

Comment: I know but the task that has been assigned to me, states clearly that i have to use pipes. I'm sorry but thank you for your answer!